# Firewall on a KVM host, prevent access to VM:s

Tags: ubuntu, networking, firewall, iptables, kvm-virtualization

I have a Linux machine running KVM with several VM:s, all have public IP:s. For the time being I have everything routed through a bridge (br0) and this works well.

I also need a firewall on the host to restrict access to both the host and the VM:s, I guess we are talking about routing and iptables? I'm not that experienced with iptables/bridging/network stuff and need a point in the right direction.

Any recommendations?

*Host: Ubuntu server 11.04, VM: Mixed, Linux and Windows*

Comment: I have a working solution, right now. I will update my question (when I have time) with the configuration/rules, or should a answer be more appropriate?

Answer (score 4):

iptables can be set up to check bridge traffic. 
I usually disable it to improve performance, but you can do the opposite:
/etc/sysctl.conf:

```
net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-ip6tables = 0
net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-iptables = 0
net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-arptables = 0
```

If you set either of these to 1 instead of 0 you'll have the host iptables filtering the traffic for the bridge.

Another solution would be to stop using the bridge, and use libvirts' NAT implementation, which uses iptables as well

EDIT: since both ways are rather faulty IMO, I would run the firewalls in the guests themselves, leaving them on a normal bridged network. or, which would be even more proper, run a separate firewall appliance in front of the virtual infrastructure

Comment: Ah, nice. I will give the "bridge routing" a try. A separate machine is not a option (cost and limited space).

Comment: @nsg: You can run OpenWRT on a low cost router and run the external firewall there.

Comment: A separate physical box is not a option. Limited space/cost.

Comment: Note that since Kernel 3.18 those settings are handled by the `br_netfilter` module