# iptables on bridged networking

Tags: networking, iptables, bridge

I need some assistance to create a set of iptable rules to route and restrict usage between interfaces in a bridge (br0).

```
# brctl show
bridge name bridge id               STP enabled     interfaces
br0           8000.002590387da2     no              eth0
                                                    vnet0
                                                    vnet1
```

I have enabled net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-ip6tables and net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-iptables (for a description of what i need, see: [Firewall on a KVM host, prevent access to VM:s](https://serverfault.com/questions/286748/firewall-on-a-kvm-host-prevent-access-to-vms)).

I'm not skilled at iptables hacking and need some help, or a point in the right direction. Right now I'm not even sure in what table/chain I'm suppose to work against.

Comment: I have a working solution, I will update this question (when I have time), or should a answer be more appropriate?

Answer (score 1):

The [Shorewall article on Bridged Firewalls](http://www.shorewall.net/bridge-Shorewall-perl.html) may help.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably read [this](http://www.netfilter.org/) to get an idea of which rules need to go where. This picture (copied from the Ubuntu wiki) provides a simple yet good overview of how traffic flows through iptables:

[image]

Comment: Yes, I will give the link a try. Thank you for the picture.